# How to resolve TS compilation error when DataTables options and TypeDefinitions are used?

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, datatables

I have created a minimal TypeScript project set up in Visual Studio.
I use the jQuery plugin DataTables. I added TypeDefinitions for jQuery and DataTables via the NuGet package manager. Everything works fine. The definitions work in general, because I am able to use IntelliSense auto completion for jQuery and DataTable functions.

But I get compiler errors as soon as I add a options object for table configuration to the DataTables constructor.

```
window.onload = () => {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var table = $('#example').DataTable({
            "paging": false
        });
    });
};
```

The first error is:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Build:Argument of type '{ "paging": false; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Settings'.    TS_DT_withoutErrors TS_DT_withoutErrors C:\project_path...\TS_DT_withoutErrors\app.ts   3

The second error is:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   TS2345  (TS) Argument of type '{ "paging": false; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Settings'.
  **Property 'oFeatures' is missing in type '{ "paging": false; }'.**   TS_DT_withoutErrors C:\project_path...\TS_DT_withoutErrors\app.ts

I can add a `"oFeatures": null,` property to the object, but that just changes the second error message to:
Property **'oScroll'** is missing in type '{ "oFeatures": null; "paging": false; }'.
I could go on and add every property the compiler demands next, but after 50+ lines I see no end in sight.

I guess the Definition file is somewhat deprecated and demands properties that are no longer a thing in DataTables or it wants internal properties that aren't meant to be altered by a user of the library, because the properties are not even mentioned in the [official documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/option/).

I know that I could configure the the build settings of the TypeScript compiler in a way that errors are ignored and the bundled and compiled js file is still emitted, but thats not really a solution for me.

**So if anyone could tell me how and where I could contribute and alter the DataTables Definitions or how I could tell the compiler to ignore these two specific errors, that would be great.**

My used packages are the following:

```
<packages>
  <package id="jQuery" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="jquery.dataTables.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped" version="0.6.7" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="jquery.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped" version="3.1.2" targetFramework="net452" />
</packages>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Easy solution (TL;DR use type any)**

I realised there is a simple solution or rather workaround for this kind of type error. Just use type `any` for the settings object.

```
var settingsObj: any = {
  "paging": false
}
var table = $('#example').DataTable(settingsObj);
```

The DataTables constructor expects an argument of type `DataTables.Settings`. When using type `any` for the settings object the typescript compiler doesn't throw an error about a wrong argument type anymore.

**Better approach**

It would probably be better to study the contents of the DataTables typedefiniton file and change the `DataTables.Settings` class to resemble the methods of the official DataTables documentation. But just using type any works fine as well.

```
var settingsObj: DataTables.Settings = {
  "paging": false
   //several properties would be expected here 
   //or should be removed from DT TypeDefinition file    
}
```